# @Version field is not added to document when using Spring Data & Couchbase

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, couchbase, versioning

I'm trying to create an object in Couchbase with a `@Version` field.

So I created a class like that ( [following this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/)  about Optimistic Locking [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/)):

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CatLock{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
private String id;

@Version
private long version;

@Field
final private String catName;
}
```

When saving the document there is no problem:

```
  CatLock catLock = CatLock.builder()
                    .catName("Oscar")
                    .build();
  catLockRepository.save(catLock);
```

But when checking the document in the DB, using the Couchbase UI, I see there is no `version` field in the document (and also there is no `id` field in it):

```
{
  "_class": "com.example.CatLock",
  "catName": "Oscar"
}
```

And when the code gets to the point where we try to read the object:

```
CatLock inDB = catLockRepository.findCatLockByCatName("Oscar");
```

We get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter version must not be null!

I tried at one point to add `version = 1L` when creating the object in the first place, but it didn't help: The code passed successfully the `catLockRepository.save(catLock)` but *nothing is saved in the DB*.

I also saw that I'm not supposed to touch/alter the `version` field.

What an I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was in the annotations of the `CatLock` class.

I changed

`@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))`

to simply

```
@AllArgsConstructor
```

And it started to work OK.